# What maven dependency is the Jetty SSL support in, and what is the correct current way to initialize SSL in Jetty 9 (embedded)?

Tags: maven, ssl, jetty

I've looked high and low and at maybe 10 different walkthroughs / blogs.   I cannot seem to find SslSelectChannelConnector in any maven POM in the latest version of Jetty (9.3)!

Has this been deprecated?  Is there any support for nio SSL through Jetty anymore (I'm embedding, so the standard distro won't do, before anyone goes suggesting that.  It's got to build through Maven).

Older versions have the old mortbay groupId, and it seems even some Eclipse POMs had it in the recent past.   But nothing in 9.3.   Tearing hair.

Comment: Off topic. Try findjar.com.

Comment: No, it's not off-topic, I'm also asking if the specific programming technique for setting up an SSL server has changed (ie. has this been deprecated).   findjar will not answer that question (and in fact does not answer either, as I already tried it)